# Getting started with GUI for student who has only worked with console

Tags: python, html, css, vba, user-interface

So far I have only been taught how to program/script at my school for console programs but wanted to start making some applications with an actual interface other then the command-line, unfortunately I have no idea where to begin. I tried to look it up but all I found were guides on how to "design" them not program them. As such I would like to ask you how exactly should I get started on this, I know this is a rather broad question but just a few links to some study material that can help me get started is enough. The languages I have been taught are Visual Basic and Python but I also know HTML and CSS, I am only slightly familiar with JavaScript.

(Bonus Question: so when looking at the website for Atom.io I saw that the editor was made in JavaScript, node.js, HTML and CSS. I was wondering how did they use HTML and CSS for a desktop app? Also, is it possible to do that without node.js and JavaScript, say for example with Python?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862410/how-do-i-actually-get-somewhere-in-gui-programming?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend begin with:

Visual Basic: [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx)(have a nice GUI editor, easier than TkInter)

Python: [TkInter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)(Everything simple with pack()).

About HTML/CSS/JS desktop app use `Electron` http://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 0):

Given you already know python , you can use python library "Tkinter" to get started.
**https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm**
**https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Graphics Py document created by John Zelle
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf